# Mule ESB XML Map to HTTP Post

Tags: xml, http, mule

I have the following Mule ESB flow. It's purpose is to read an XML, map it and then submit a set of fields to an API via HTTP post.

I am getting no data posting to the API and this error message. I believe my issue is not being able to properly set the output properties such as this one for area.

org.mule.transformer.simple.MessagePropertiesTransformer: Property with key 'area', not found on message using '#[message.outboundProperties['area']]'. Since the value was marked optional, nothing was set on the message for this property

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:data-mapper="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper/current/mule-data-mapper.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
    <data-mapper:config name="XML_To_XML" transformationGraphPath="xml_to_xml.grf" doc:name="XML_To_XML"/>
    <flow name="Flow1" doc:name="Flow1">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="/Users/dylan/Documents/Projects/Mulesoft/XMLin" moveToDirectory="/Users/dylan/Documents/Projects/Mulesoft/XMLout" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <data-mapper:transform config-ref="XML_To_XML" doc:name="XML To XML">
            <data-mapper:input-arguments>
            </data-mapper:input-arguments>
        </data-mapper:transform>
        <message-properties-transformer doc:name="send-check-api">
            <add-message-property key="source_id" value="#[message.outboundProperties['source_id']]"/>
            <add-message-property key="country" value="#[message.outboundProperties['country']]"/>
            <add-message-property key="region" value="#[message.outboundProperties['region']]"/>
            <add-message-property key="area" value="#[message.outboundProperties['area']]"/>
            <add-message-property key="city" value="#[message.outboundProperties['city']]"/>
            <add-message-property key="source_agentid" value="#[message.outboundProperties['source_agentid']]"/>
            <add-message-property key="status" value="#[message.outboundProperties['status']]"/>
            <add-message-property key="source" value="#[message.outboundProperties['source']]"/>
        </message-properties-transformer>
        <set-property propertyName="http.method" value="#[flowVars['send-check-api']]" doc:name="set-post-attributes"/>
        <logger level="DEBUG" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="XX.XX.XX.com" port="80" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" path="v1/property/check"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The outbound properties inside the `message-properties-transformers` are unlikely to exist. IIRC datamapper's outbound attribute are translated into flow vars.

That would also explain the whole `message-properties-transformer` meaning, because like it is right now, is copying VAR_X into VAR_X.